# Switching Azure search to SOLR search in Sitecore 10.2

Tags: solr, sitecore-client

We are doing the upgradation of Sitecore from 9.0 to 10.2. In that we need to switch the Azure to SOLR.
We have updated all connection strings and other config files which are required for Solr. Is there any to be modified in backend code?

Comment: Worth to note when we upgraded to 10.2 and Solr i had to modify our custom Solr configuration to be case insensitive on searching, while for some reason it was default for Azure in our instance. For a code itself, I don't reckon i had to change anything as Sitecore Content Search Api worked seamlessly here.

Comment: need to update the custom search that you have implemented in your project. ensure in web.config search:define value you should be in Solr. all CloudSearchconfiguration should be SolrSearchconfiguration

Answer (score 1):

I have found that there are differences in the implementation in Solr vs Azure Search for things like Contains, StartsWith, EndsWith and Like, so when going the other way (Solr > Azure - as recommended at the time) for custom search implementations I had to change some of the code that handled this. It does depend on what custom code you have in place though. In my experience Solr is better at these kind of Queries.

There are details here on the Azure limitations from Sitecore here:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/sitecore-azure-search-overview.html

Answer (score 1):

I went through the `Sitecore documentation` but didn't find a particular for migrating from `Azure` to `Solr` for `Sitecore 10.2`. However, if I check the document for migrating from `Lucene` to `Solr`, it shows some code updates on the queries. Like StatsWith, EndsWith etc.

Here is the document link.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/moving-from-lucene-to-solr.html

So I assume that there will be some code updates if you want to get the desired result.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you perform all the other configurations so assuming you did it for XP and XConnect, also perform the schema updates and did the indexing for Sitecore and Xconnect both so just jumping on the coding part here.

Most probably you don't need to update any code as the limitations are in Azure Side. But Since your existing results are using Azure and based on your code you may face issues in getting the same results in search using Solr for a few cases. For example, tokenization works differently in Azure and Solr so when you pass multiple keywords or with space terms, the results may differ in both Solr and Azure, you may see fewer results in Solr compared to Azure in this case. Facet values are also not tokenized in Solr but in Azure it is. I would suggest you perform all these operations and do testing on lower environments and make sure everything is working as expected after switching to Solr search.